# "The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." error after hosting

Tags: php, laravel, host

so I have my laravel blade project working exactly as it should locally. the problem is that once I uploaded it on my host (using hosting as the web host), the website sort of crashed. now, it says that the put method is not supported any more for this route, which is weird as the website was working fine locally here is a snippet of the error I keep getting now. I hope someone has encountered this issue and knows the work-around for it. thank you

Comment: Can you post your route file (probably `routes/web.php` or `routes/api.php`), and more details about which route you want to access, where etc.. Without more information, it's a very hard game for us to help you :p

Comment: Maybe tour host provider limited HTTP methods to just GET and POST.

Comment: show us your URL call + route files.

Answer (score 0):

There might be below issues -

1. It might be some cache issue. Clear cache on Local & live both, then check the error.
2. You might have defined multiple routes with the same name & different request methods. Make sure they are not conflicting.
3. Other than that, it can be something related to hosting, composer version.

Give us some more references, so that we could reach to a perfect solution.